# SQL find rows in the same table based on certain columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which are for two different programs. Each program has a specific program_instance (the program_instance) is the year of the program.

One table is called 'enrollees' and the other is 'nominations' - for two programs that aren't technically related.

I've been trying to get the count of past participants from both tables. For reference:

program_instance_id:

- 5 = GC 2014
- 3 = GC 2013
- 1 = GC 2012
- 4 = GE 2013
- 2 = GE 2012

So I ran this query on my enrollees table and it produced a result in 913ms:

```
SELECT      count(*) AS prev_enrollees
FROM       outreach.enrollees e1
WHERE e1.program_instance_id = 5 AND EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM outreach.enrollees e2
            WHERE e1.first_name = e2.first_name 
            AND e1.last_name = e2.last_name 
            AND e1.address1 = e2.address1 
            AND e1.state = e2.state 
            AND e1.zip = e2.zip 
            AND e2.program_instance_id < 5);
```

This query, to my understanding, would give me the number of rows in the 'enrollees' table where an enrollee from the current year (program_instance_id = 5) had previous enrolled in another year. The result it produces is pretty accurate, to my understanding.

So... I ran this EXACT query (changing the table name) on my 'nominations' table. The nominations table has almost the exact structure of the 'enrollees' table (some columns are different, but the person's information fields are identical). This query ran for over a half hour before I cancelled it. It's not popping out an almost-instant result like it was on the enrollee table and I don't know why it would take longer.

I could imagine if there were a lot more rows in the table but the enrollee table has about 50k MORE rows than the nominations table.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT     count(*) AS prev_enrollees
FROM       outreach_grow_education.nominations e1
JOIN  outreach_grow_education.nominations e2 ON e1.first_name = e2.first_name 
AND e1.last_name = e2.last_name 
AND e1.address1 = e2.address1 
AND e1.state = e2.state 
AND e1.zip = e2.zip 
AND 4 = e2.program_instance_id
WHERE e1.id IS NOT NULL AND e1.program_instance_id = 2;
```

Alas, to the same result. Instant result on enrollees, never-ending on nominations.

Is there any other alternative for what I'm trying to achieve that wouldn't cause the never-ending cycle?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Please use the correct database tag on the question.  This is especially important for performance-based questions.

Comment: Sorry, it's MySQL. Sad as it is to say, I didn't know there was a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest checking the indexes of the two tables, specifically for the columns you use in the JOIN clauses: first_name, last_name, address1, state, zip, and program_instance_id. Chances are one or more of these columns is indexed in the "enrollees" table and not in "nominations."

Comment: I was just reading about indexes as I got the notification about your answer. That is exactly what it was. I apparently have a lot of learning to do with databases. Thank you.